# Chrome / Opera / Vivaldi extension save regexp to chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser

I'm looking to save regex to chrome.storage.local but from the dev manual I'm not able to do this, so I forge for your assistance.

What I want:
1. The ext to save regex calculation to chrome.storage.local
2. Seek calculation from storage.local instead of burning CPU to do regex every time
3. Does that calc from storage.local need clearing?
4. Could my regexp be more efficient?
5. Should I have "use strict"?

Purpose of the ext:
i) work when text written or pasted to omnibox/address bar
ii) always use https
iii) always use encrypted.google.com (when on *.Google.*)

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    var requestURL = details.url;
var gglrex = new RegExp('^(https?):\/\/www\.google\.(?:(?!com\/)[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z]+)?\/', 'i');
    return {
      redirectUrl: requestURL.replace(gglrex, '$1://encrypted.google.com/')
    };
  },
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['blocking']
);
```

So obviously gglrex is what I want to save to chrome storage local set. Please I hope you can help me.

Comment: Simply evaluate it on the start of your background page and store the result in a global variable, then use it in the listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm I hav tested few methods but can't get none to work, with every google search it fires up the calculation. I thought I almost gave up but decided I want this functionality in this ext. In addition to saving does it need to be cleared too? ANd what about my regex... Could it be slimmer?

Comment: Well, don't give up. BTW, the ideal approach is to specify URL filter in addListener instead of all_urls, you can check the documentation or [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:onbeforerequest).

Comment: AS mentioned, don't create the RegEx inside your listener, unless you *must*, which is not the case here. There's no reason to be doing that in the listener. Do it outside the listener and allow the listener to access it as a variable.

Comment: Please keep your Questions to one question per Question. Questions which contain multiple questions which are not *very* tightly related are considered too broad and tend to be closed. The reason for this is that the Stack Overflow format is intended to provide a base of questions and answers which are useful to people in the future, not just the person currently asking. Questions with multiple issues tend to be too specific to be useful to others searching for help to their problems. Often, to solve a larger issue it is necessary to combine the answers from multiple questions.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Are you asking for us to show you how to store a RegExp in `storage.local`? The code you've provided isn't showing anything about `storage.local`, so I'm confused as to what you really want here.

Comment: @makyen yes pretty much. My background is html, css and php and it seems a bit overwhelming to get this ext to the next level disared. In the JSON manifest all country specific google.zzz urls specified - so <all_urls> not needed? Yes regex should got to storage.local. The ext works now and is pretty fast and efficient, so I hesitate not to change it much, but it's also troublesome with rexex calculating over and over again.

Comment: This is a bit overwhelming: Store regex in storage.local and make the ext use it. Also move regex away from listener. But i'm not gonna quit - I've been reading guides and tutorials and inspected sampe ext's  but still I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Hmm: storage.local.set gglregex.lastIndex = 0

Comment: Please help? Me a bit?

Comment: I was thinking should I use this page rather as event page or plain background page? People aren't using Google all the time, but then again, people use Google in addition to other browsing - so quite frequently.